# Rearranging groupings in bar chart from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want a grouped bar chart, but the default plot doesn't have the groupings the way I'd like, and I'm struggling to get them rearranged properly.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
     user  year  cat1  cat2  cat3  cat4  cat5
0    Brad  2014   309   186   119   702    73
1    Brad  2015   280   177   100   625    75
2    Brad  2016   306   148   127   671    74
3   Brian  2014   298   182   131   702    73
4   Brian  2015   295   125   117   607    76
5   Brian  2016   298   137    97   596    75
6   Chris  2014   309   171   111   654    72
7   Chris  2015   251   146   105   559    76
8   Chris  2016   231   130   105   526    75
etc
```

Elsewhere, the code produces two variables, user1 and user2. I want to produce a bar chart that compares the numbers for those two users over time in cat1, cat2, and cat3. So for example if user1 and user2 were Brian and Chris, I would want a chart that looks something like this:

[image: grouped bar chart]

On an aesthetic note: I'd prefer the year labels be vertical text or a font size that fits on a single line, but it's really the dataframe pivot that's confusing me at the moment.

Comment: Do you want the bars to be grouped like the above shown or you want them to have alternate groups?

Comment: The above is my ideal (aside from the ugly conflicts on the year labels).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the subset of users you want to plot against. Use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) later to transform the `DF` to the required format to be plotted by transposing and unstacking it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def select_user_plot(user_1, user_2, cats, frame, idx, col):
    frame = frame[(frame[idx[0]] == user_1)|(frame[idx[0]] == user_2)]
    frame_pivot = frame.pivot_table(index=idx, columns=col, values=cats).T.unstack()
    frame_pivot.plot.bar(legend=True, cmap=plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn'), figsize=(8,8), rot=0)
```

Finally,

Choose the users and categories to be included in the bar plot.

```
user_1 = 'Brian'
user_2 = 'Chris'
cats = ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3']

select_user_plot(user_1, user_2, cats, frame=df, idx=['user'], col=['year'])
```

[image]

Note: This gives close to the plot that the OP had posted.(Year appearing as Legends instead of the tick labels)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was getting things all twisted around with pivots and unstacks; I appreciate the help.

Comment: Same here. Took me a while to figure it out completely.